# Extending asp.net membership database

Tags: asp.net, .net, database-design, architecture

I'm building a new asp.net web forms based system . I want to use the membership database as my identity store . I can take the membership database and start adding my own system tables , but I think to separate them , means , membership db  in stand alone, then I have to make a link from my db with some mapping users table to the membership user . 
Is the an automatic way to sync both DBS , or maybe you have another solution .

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

You should have 1 database. Create an empty database. Run the aspnet_regsql.exe tool. Add your own tables.

Comment: I need to use the membership db for more than one application to authenticate so I think it doesnot make sence to mix extra business table on it !

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100).aspx